# Split pdf using string python

Tags: python, pdf, split

I have a big pdf that I need to split into smaller pdfs using a string. I can split pdfs by page, but I don't know how to do it using a specific string and save it as a new pdf. For example, if I see "07.5" I want to split it before this string. Is there anyway to do that in python? I have been researching, but didn't have any luck finding something.

Here is the code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(r"file.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open(r"file-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

Comment: Where's your [mre]? And what are you stuck on? If you can already split PDFs it's not clear what you're asking for. How are you currently splitting them? How do you want the splitting to work? Splitting strings on specific text is simple, as well as finding the index of a certain substring in a string, but as far as splitting the PDF itself, we'd have to see how you're doing it to be able to say how to split on specific text, I think, since your post is very vague and unclear. Maybe see [ask] for some tips.

Comment: Just attached code

Answer (score 1):

If assuming your PDF is purely text and you don't care for the formatting, you should be able to extract the entire text body within the PDF and then you can doing the splitting operations in Python afterwards.

A quick glance at https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-245482a96de7 seems to suggest that there are methods to extract said text with various pythons libraries.

I have a code snippet below - some stuff you'll have to fill in the gaps but it's the general idea:

```
text_content = inputpdf.read() # Sorry, not familiar with library 

# produces list of strings delimited by that string
splitted_content = text_content.split("07.5") 

# add back the delimiter to each of the splitted text
splitted_content = [i + "07.5" for i in splitted_content] 

# output separate files afterwards
for c in splitted_content:
    pass
```

Comment: I can extract it no problem, but I need to split it using a specific string.

Comment: @Sammi Your code snippet is currently splitting page by page and outputting it as a separate PDF. If you are looking to split the text content by specific strings, I would recommend loading the text content into one variable, then perform your string operations afterwards.

I would make use of the built-in string methods. Try looking at the documentation for find() and/or split(). You should be able to separate the text content that way, then you can output it afterwards.